# How soon after leaving SA can I obtain a new tourist visa?

Tags: visas, south-africa

I was in South Africa for nearly 3 months on a 90 day tourist visa. I departed on November 1st. How long must I be abroad now before I can re-enter and obtain a new 90 day tourist visa?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I went to Mauritius for 5 days and I was able to reenter SA without a problem. They don't have a set time frame but they do watch for border hoping, for example if  you just go to Botswana for a couple days and come back they will only give you the remainder of your 90 days, or 7 days to gather your things and leave.